# WSO2 APIM Clustering - populating updates to gateways

Tags: wso2, synchronized, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

Looking at the following [WSO2 clustering](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/API+Manager+Clustering+Deployment+Patterns#APIManagerClusteringDeploymentPatterns-Maincomponentsofadistributedsetup)  documentation, it seems as the only way WSO2 gateways are updated with API's info is by publisher pushing the information to the gateway via HTTPs port.

There are a few questions which are not clear from this document

1. Does the publisher have to push any API update to every specific gateway instance in the cloud? Suppose there are 10 gateways - does each API update sent to all those 10 instances? or is there another mechanism? (another WSO2 document referred to a "master" gateway and mentioned the use of svn, but still not sure how synchronization is done).
2. What happens once a gateway is restarted, or in case a new gateway is added to the cluster? How does it sync with all the information which was "pushed" earlier, when it was not up or before it was added?

According to the diagram, the gateways do not access the database, so there must be a different mechanism to keep them all synced, but I could not find a clear information about how it is done in WSO2 documentation.

Comment: [tag:clustering] is an alias for [tag:cluster-analysis], a data mining technique. The term "clustering" is ambiguous. Please tag more carefully.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your both question, here is the answer,

WSO2 API Manager (all the WSO2 products) uses [SVN Deployment Synchronizer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Introduction+to+Deployment+Synchronizer).

You can have a look on [Configuring SVN-Based Deployment Synchronizer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer) as well. Master node pushes the artifacts to a SVN repo, and all the worker nodes will pick up the latest changes.

All the administration works should be carried on master, and through SVN worker node will get the changes.